# How to inject custom list of beans in spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, dependency-injection, javabeans

Assume that all `BarX` are children of `Foo` type.

My bean configuration class is:

```java
class MyConfig{
    @Bean
    public Foo barA() {
        return new BarA();
    }

    @Bean
    public Foo barB() {
        return new BarB();
    }

    @Bean
    public Foo barC() {
        return new BarC();
    }

    @Bean
    public List<Foo> getDefaultFoos(BarA barA, BarB barB) {
        return List.of(barA, barB);
    }

    @Bean
    public OtherType other(List<Foo> defaultFoos, ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        return new OtherType(defaultFoos, applicationContext); 
        /* Expecting `List<Foo> defaultFoos` from method `getDefaultFoos` which is [barA, barB] 
        but getting list of all Bars which is [barA, barB, barC]
        */
    }
}
```

In method `OtherType other`,

Expecting `List<Foo> defaultFoos` from method `getDefaultFoos` which is `[barA, barB]` only but getting list of all Bars which is `[barA, barB, barC]`

How to inject a custom list Foo instead of all of it in 'other' bean?

Comment: do you need `defaultFoos` bean somewhere else?

Comment: Not in the current context but possible yes. Please suggest the solution anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [@Qualifier](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/Qualifier.html) to specify the exact bean you need.

```
@Bean
public OtherType other(@Qualifier("getDefaultFoos") List<Foo> defaultFoos, ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
  return new OtherType(defaultFoos, applicationContext);
}
```

When you autowire a list of something, the default behaviour is to get every bean matching, which you are seeing here.